# JUnit: using constructor instead of @Before

Tags: java, junit, constructor, initialization

I'm using JUnit 4. I can't see the difference between initializing in the constructor or using a dedicated init function annotated by `@Before`. Does this mean that I don't have to worry about it?

Is there any case when `@Before` gives more than just initializing in the constructor?

Comment: possible duplicate of [setUp/tearDown (@Before/@After) why we need them in JUnit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648712/setup-teardown-before-after-why-we-need-them-in-junit)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512184/best-practice-initialize-junit-class-fields-in-setup-or-at-declaration

Comment: Are you sure you mean `@Before`, not `@BeforeClass`? Check the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295578/difference-between-before-beforeclass-beforeeach-and-beforeall).

Answer (score 111, accepted):

No, using the constructor to initialize your JUnit test fixture is technically equal to using the `@Before` method (due to the fact that JUnit creates a new instance of the testing class for each `@Test`). The only (connotational) difference is that it breaks the symmetry between `@Before` and `@After`, which may be confusing for some. IMHO it is better to adhere to conventions (which is using `@Before`).

Note also that prior to JUnit 4 and annotations, there were dedicated `setUp()` and `tearDown()` methods - the `@Before` and `@After` annotations replace these, but preserve the underlying logic. So using the annotations also makes life easier for someone migrating from JUnit 3 or earlier versions.

### Notable differences

More details from comments:

- `@Before` allows overriding parent class behavior, constructors force you to call parent class constructors
- The constructor runs *before* subclass constructors and `@Rule` methods, `@Before` runs *after* all of those
- Exceptions during `@Before` cause `@After` methods to be called, Exceptions in constructor don't

Comment: @Before is not called multiple times ? (before each test method ?)

Comment: @Sylvain, as JUnit creates a new test class instance for each test method, the constructor and `@Before` is called exactly the same amount of times.

Comment: In the meantime I've read an important difference: if an *exception is thrown in the constructor* then there will be no object to run `@After` on. So I've kept using the annotations and only keep the minimal constructor.

Comment: One difference is that code in the constructor will be executed before any Rules are applied. If you have Rules that do something before running the test, that code is executed before any @Before methods

Comment: @PéterTörök, I agree that it is better to adhere to conventions, which is why I prefer to use constructors to initialize my test objects instead of `@Before` methods.  IMHO, `@Before` violates one of the most important Java conventions, that of relying on the constructor to initalize objects! (Not to mention, I can make my class members `final` and the IDE or compiler will tell me when I forgot to initialize a member.)

Comment: @vbence, won't the test fail if the constructor or an `@After` method fails?

Comment: @DerekMahar I'm sure it will (if exception is not the goal of the test). But you might want to clean up after setting up the test if external state (filesystem/database) is involved. - Those are not typical unit tests though.

Comment: @DerekMahar, there are always different circles of convention in play, and IMHO it is usually recommended to adhere to the most specific of these, which in this case is JUnit. YMMV. Note that the point of the Java (or rather, general OO) convention of using constructors is to ensure that objects are always properly initialized before usage. In JUnit, these specific objects represent test cases, and are initialized and used only by the framework itself, in a very specific and strict way which guarantees proper setup and teardown.

Comment: @DerekMahar, not to mention that not all xUnit clones behave the same way in this respect. E.g. NUnit does not create a new instance of the test class for each test method execution, so using the constructor instead of the `[SetUp]` method (the NUnit equivalent of `@Before`) would actually be an error there. To me this is analogous to the "rely on interfaces, not implementations" maxime, making one's code more portable and easier to maintain in the long run.

Comment: @PéterTörök, I did not know that NUnit did not follow this convention.  I think you've convinced me that using `@Before` is a good idea, though it bothers me that when using `@Before`, I can't make my data member references final.

Answer (score 32):

@Before makes more sense to use in certain cases because it gets called AFTER the constructor for the class.  This difference is important when you're using a mock framework like Mockito with @Mock annotations, because your @Before method will be called after the mocks are initialized.  Then you can use your mocks to provide constructor arguments to the class under test.

I find this to be a very common pattern in my unit tests when using collaborating beans.

Here's an (admittedly contrived) example:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CalculatorTest {
    @Mock Adder adder;
    @Mock Subtractor subtractor;
    @Mock Divider divider;
    @Mock Multiplier multiplier;

    Calculator calculator;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        calculator = new Calculator(adder,subtractor,divider,multiplier);
    }

    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        BigDecimal value = calculator.add(2,2);
        verify(adder).add(eq(2),eq(2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you do the same thing in a constructor?  In a constructor, just initialize the calculator with all the mocks which the test runner should have initialized first.

Comment: Also, you defined those Mocks to be @Nonnull. You need a constructor to fix that. A setUp() method won’t to, because you can instantiate the CalculatorTest-class in another test, which will then cause NPEs.

Answer (score 14):

I prefer to use constructors to initialize my test objects because it allows me to make all the members `final` so that the IDE or compiler will tell me when the *constructor* forgot to initialize a member and prevent another method from setting them.

IMHO, `@Before` violates one of the most important Java conventions, that of relying on the constructor to completely initalize objects!

JUnit 5 also has better support for constructor injection.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer to declare my fixtures as final and initialize them inline or in the constructor so I don't forget to initialize them! However, since exceptions thrown in @Before are handled in a more user-friendly way, I usually initialize the object under test in @Before.

Answer (score 4):

Quote from http://etutorials.org/Programming/Java+extreme+programming/Chapter+4.+JUnit/4.6+Set+Up+and+Tear+Down/

> You may be wondering why you should write a setUp( ) method instead of
>   simply initializing fields in a test case's constructor. After all,
>   since a new instance of the test case is created for each of its test
>   methods, the constructor is always called before setUp( ). In a vast
>   majority of cases, you can use the constructor instead of setUp( )
>   without any side effects.
>
> In cases where your test case is part of a deeper inheritance
>   hierarchy, you may wish to postpone object initialization until
>   instances of derived classes are fully constructed. This is a good
>   technical reason why you might want to use setUp( ) instead of a
>   constructor for initialization. Using setUp( ) and tearDown( ) is also
>   good for documentation purposes, simply because it may make the code
>   easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

There is one thing that *constructor* can archive but not *@Before*.

You have to use a constructor when you need to initial fields defined in parent class. For example:

```
abstract class AbstractIT {
   int fieldAssignedInSubClass;
   public AbstractIT(int fieldAssignedInSubClass) {
      this.fieldAssignedInSubClass= fieldAssignedInSubClass;
   }

   @Before
   void before() {
      // comsume fieldAssignedInSubClass
   } 
}

public class ChildIT extends AbstractIT{
   public ChildIT() {
      // assign fieldAssignedInSubClass by constructor
      super(5566); 
   }

   @Before
   void before() {
      // you cannot assign fieldAssignedInSubClass by a @Before method
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Before` does make sense to use for several reasons. It makes your test code more readable. It matches `@After` annotation which is responsible for releasing used resources and is a counterpart of the `@BeforeClass` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference except that the constructor is the only method ehere can initialize the @Rule objects:

```
public class TestClass {

    @Rule
    public SomeRule rule;

    public TestClass() {
        // code to initialize the rule field
        conf = new RuleConf()
        rule = new SomeRule(conf)
    }
}
```