# @After ,@before not working in testcase

Tags: java, junit, testcase

I have started testing and now i want to use `@After`, `@Before` and `@Test` but my application only runs the `@Before` method and gives output on console

> before

However, if I remove `@After` and `@Before` it runs the @Test. My code is here:

```
public class TestPractise extends AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests{

    @Before
    public void runBare(){
        System.out.println("before");
    }

    @Test
    public void testingMethod(){
        System.out.println("testing");
    }

    @After
    public void setDirty(){
        System.out.println("after");
    }
}
```

Why aren't `@After`, `@Test` and `@before` working simultaneously?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests` class forces the use of the old JUnit 3.x syntax, which means that any of the JUnit 4 annotation will not work.

Your method `runBare()` is executed not because of the `@Before` annotation, but because it is named `runBare()`, which is a method provided by `ConditionalTestCase` and JUnit [`TestCase`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/junit3.8.1/javadoc/junit/framework/TestCase.html#runBare%28%29) class.

So you have 2 solutions:

- Use the AlexR answer to use JUnit 4 tests and Spring;
- Keep your inheritance of `AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests`, but use the `onSetUp` and `onTearDown` methods instead of the `@Before` and `@After` methods.

Comment: Got this same problem mixing up JUnit 4 and 5. Check your imports for the annotations and make sure they match.

Answer (score 76):

Use `@BeforeEach` instead of `@Before` and `@AfterEach` instead of `@After`.

Comment: Could you add a little bit of an explanation about why and how this solves the problem?

Comment: In my case my "@Before" and "@After" code was not running, but it worked when i replaced "@Before" with "@BeforeEach" and "@After" and "@AfterEach".

Comment: It's just more specific names working is same. But support (Execution) is depends on Junit version.

Comment: dude! I spent hours figuring this out!

Comment: Just keep in mind this creates alot of wasted execution.  BeforeEach resets everything *before* every test is run.  This could be desirable but unnecessary for example, when loading a file for test parameters or one-time file reads for the class.

Answer (score 20):

Check that you are using Junit4 because from Junit5 onwards @Before/@After is now @BeforeEach/@AfterEach and similalry @BeforeClass/@AfterClass is @AfterAll/@BeforeAll.

Answer (score 7):

It should work... But since you are working with spring framework and JUnit 4 was introduced years ago I's suggest you to use annotations instead of inheritance.

So, annotate you class with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`. Remove `extends AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests`.

Don't forget to make the [@Before](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) and @After methods **static**

Now it should work.

Even if you want to extend Spring abstract test classes at least pay attention that some of them are deprecated. For example class `AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests` is deprecated.

Comment: Would you please provide me a example for  @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) ??

Comment: if you write a example for AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests that would be good..

Comment: Sorry for delay. The example is very simple. Just remove "extends..." and add annotation I wrote to class. Then try to run the test.

Answer (score 6):

## JUnit Jupiter, aka "JUnit 5": use `@BeforeAll`

If you use the newer JUnit Jupiter (Java 8 onward), you'll want to replace `@Before` with `@BeforeAll`.

Furthermore, you'll need to either annotate your test class with `@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)` or make the `@BeforeAll` method `static`.  Here's an example:

```java
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class MyTestClass {

    MyHeavyResource sharedResource;

    @BeforeAll
    void init() {
        System.out.println("init");
        sharedResource = new MyHeavyResource(1234);
    }

    @Test
    void myTest() {
        System.out.println("myTest");
        sharedResource.methodUnderTest();
    }
}
```

### Understanding `Lifecycle.PER_CLASS`

The likely reason JUnit 5 is more stringent with this -- demanding either `static` or `Lifecycle.PER_CLASS` -- is that it wants the test author to acknowledge that any resource instance initialized in a `@BeforeAll` method will genuinely be shared across each individual unit test method within the class.  This could compromise their isolation, for example if the `sharedResource` in the above example isn't stateless/idempotent.

If `sharedResource` cannot be safely shared  (or if it's reasonably leightweight), the `init` method should be annotated with `@BeforeEach` instead, which would create a new instance before executing each individual test within the class.

[The Javadoc for `TestInstance`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/TestInstance.Lifecycle.html#PER_CLASS) explain how using `Lifecycle.PER_CLASS` actually enforces a single instance of the test class; whereas the behaviour of JUnit 4 and earlier was equivalent to `Lifecycle.PER_METHOD`, which created a new instance of the test class for each `@Test` method contained therein.  This would somewhat mislead the author to suppose that `@Before` was only executed once for each of those tests.

Answer (score 3):

If you use auto import in an IDE, make sure the `@Test` and `@Before` are imported from the `org.junit` package.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I had that problem the solution was to change the java access modifier, It was way private.

before (not working)
@Test
void validate() throws Exception {}

after (working)
@Test
public void validate() throws Exception {}

Answer (score 0):

- In my case I just moved stuff from `@Before` / `@BeforeEach` annotated `setUp()` method to the constructor of my unit-test class.
- As per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6094143/3679900) using constructor is 'equivalent' to `@Before` method

I can't explain why it fixed the problem but I was facing this in one particular class and it did indeed do the trick.