# Junit test not reverting data

Tags: java, junit, testcase

I have make some testcases in junit and after testing the methods it is not reverting data from database. 
For this I have inserted some data to database. and then I tested the method.so after finishing the test data must be deleted , but it is not happening. 
Here is my code

```
public class TestAdminMethodsWebService extends AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests {
protected WebServiceTemplate admin;
Connection connection = null;
public TestAdminMethodsWebService(){
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
protected String[] getConfigLocations() {
    return new String[] { "applicationContext-test.xml" };
}
public WebServiceTemplate getAdmin() {
    return admin;
}
public void setAdmin(WebServiceTemplate admin) {
    this.admin = admin;
}
@Override
protected void onSetUp() throws Exception{  
    String query1 = "INSERT INTO roles( id,is_active,name) VALUES ('1',true,'admin')";
    String query2 = "INSERT INTO customers(id, is_active, name, lxg_username, lxg_password, lxg_classid) VALUES ('1', true,'cust1','naomi@mkinetic.com','5966nM','INFO1' )";
    String query3 = "INSERT INTO users(id,  is_active)  VALUES ('1',  true)";
    String query4 = "INSERT INTO customers(id,  is_active)  VALUES ('1',true)";
    String query5 = "INSERT INTO users( id, is_active,email, password, lxg_username, lxg_password, lxg_classid, role_id, customer_id) VALUES ('1',true,'gfe@gfe.com','gfe','naomi@mkinetic.com','5966nM','INFO1','1','1')";
    String query6 = "INSERT INTO roles( id,is_active,name) VALUES ('2',true,'User') ";

    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/g","g", "root");
        Statement st = connection.createStatement();
        st.execute(query1);
        st.execute(query2);
        st.execute(query3);
        st.execute(query4);
        st.execute(query5);
        st.execute(query6);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
@Override
protected void onTearDown() throws Exception{
    String query1 = "delete from users where id='1'";
    String query2 = "delete from roles where id='1'";
    String query3 = "delete from customers where id='1'";
    String query4 = "delete from users where id='1'";
    String query5 = "delete from customers where id='1'";
    String query6 = "delete from roles where id ='2'";
    try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/g","g", "root");
            Statement st = connection.createStatement();
            st.execute(query1);
            st.execute(query2);
            st.execute(query3);
            st.execute(query4);
            st.execute(query5);
            st.execute(query6);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
@SuppressWarnings("unckecked")
@Test
public void test_AddCompany(){
    try{
    AddCompany addCompany = new ObjectFactory().createAddCompany();
    com.gfe.services.soap.admin.AddCompany.AdminCredentials adminCredentials = new com.gfe.services.soap.admin.AddCompany.AdminCredentials();
    adminCredentials.setPassword("gfe");
    adminCredentials.setUsername("gfe@gfe.com");
    com.gfe.services.soap.admin.AddCompany.CompanyInfo companyInfo = new com.gfe.services.soap.admin.AddCompany.CompanyInfo();
    companyInfo.setCompanyKey("company1");
    companyInfo.setLxgPassword("5966nM");
    companyInfo.setLxgUsername("naomi@mkinetic.com");
    companyInfo.setName("gfe1");
    companyInfo.setUrl("http://www.google.com");
    addCompany.setAdminCredentials(adminCredentials);
    addCompany.setCompanyInfo(companyInfo);
    JAXBElement<AddCompanyResponse> xmlResponse = (JAXBElement<AddCompanyResponse>) admin.marshalSendAndReceive(addCompany);
    AddCompanyResponse response = xmlResponse.getValue();
    CompanyResponse companyResponse =response.getReturn();
    BaseErrorResponseBean baseErrorResponseBean = companyResponse.getError();
    if (baseErrorResponseBean!= null) {
        String errorCdoe = baseErrorResponseBean.getErrorCode();
        String errorMessage = baseErrorResponseBean.getErrorMessage();
        System.out.println("Error code = " +errorCdoe);
        System.out.println("Error Message = " + errorMessage);
    }
    String transactionId = companyResponse.getTransactionId();
    Boolean success = companyResponse.isSuccess();
    if (success) {
        System.out.println("The test addCompany runned successfully");  
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Some error occoured in test addCompany ");
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("ERROR IN TRY BLOCK");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: looks like mixing of junit3 and junit4

Comment: do u know what should be done ???

Comment: possibly this? :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580613/after-before-not-working-in-testcase. Use AfterClass and BeforeClass, it's junit4 style.

Comment: hey this question was also asked by me .. haha

Comment: remove the @Test annotaton from the test method then, if you want to go the junit 3 way.

Comment: alright i have found the answer .. anyway thanks

Comment: If you have an answer please post it as an answer, so that future visitors might profit from it!

Comment: Hey I was running the testcases from accessing webservice ..

Comment: Now I cant answer my own question, dont have enough reputation..

Comment: +1 to get reputation to answer it ;)

Comment: Please answer the question yourself for documentation for other users.

Answer (score 0):

you should be using dbunit instead of a real database. You want to unit test it