# Difference between @Before, @BeforeClass, @BeforeEach and @BeforeAll

Tags: java, junit, annotations, junit4, junit5

What is the main difference between

- `@Before` and `@BeforeClass`

  - and in JUnit 5 `@BeforeEach` and `@BeforeAll`
- `@After` and `@AfterClass`

According to the [JUnit Api](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/) `@Before` is used in the following case:

> When writing tests, it is common to find that several tests need similar objects created before they can run.

Whereas `@BeforeClass` can be used to establish a database connection. But couldn't `@Before` do the same?

Answer (score 752, accepted):

The code marked `@Before` is executed before each test, while `@BeforeClass` runs once before the entire test fixture. If your test class has ten tests, `@Before` code will be executed ten times, but `@BeforeClass` will be executed only once.

In general, you use `@BeforeClass` when multiple tests need to share the same computationally expensive setup code. Establishing a database connection falls into this category. You can move code from `@BeforeClass` into `@Before`, but your test run may take longer. Note that the code marked `@BeforeClass` is run as static initializer, therefore it will run before the class instance of your test fixture is created.

In [JUnit 5](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/), the tags `@BeforeEach` and `@BeforeAll` are the equivalents of `@Before` and `@BeforeClass` in JUnit 4. Their names are a bit more indicative of when they run, loosely interpreted: 'before each tests' and 'once before all tests'.

Comment: @pacoverflow `@BeforeClas` is static. It runs before test class instances are created.

Comment: Keep in mind that when you use @BeforeClass your method/parameter needs to be static

Comment: It is not directly related, but this is a way to [compute 'Tests by Category' counter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53778167/10524205).

Comment: I will only add that `@BeforeAll` may be non-static and call on every new test-instance run. See the corresponding answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55720750/1477873

Comment: are you sure `Before` and `BeforeEach` are the same things because my test cases fail the mocks when i use `@Before` on my `init()` function but works with `@BeforeEach`

Comment: @fireball.1Same thing is happening with me.

Comment: @shiva This means that you are running JUnit4, because `@Before` and `@BeforeEach` do not coexist. [See the migration guide for the information](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4-tips).

Answer (score 175):

**Difference between each annotation  are :**

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
¦                                       Feature                            ¦   Junit 4    ¦   Junit 5   ¦
¦--------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------¦
¦ Execute before all test methods of the class are executed.               ¦ @BeforeClass ¦ @BeforeAll  ¦
¦ Used with static method.                                                 ¦              ¦             ¦
¦ For example, This method could contain some initialization code          ¦              ¦             ¦
¦-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------¦
¦ Execute after all test methods in the current class.                     ¦ @AfterClass  ¦ @AfterAll   ¦
¦ Used with static method.                                                 ¦              ¦             ¦
¦ For example, This method could contain some cleanup code.                ¦              ¦             ¦
¦-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------¦
¦ Execute before each test method.                                         ¦ @Before      ¦ @BeforeEach ¦
¦ Used with non-static method.                                             ¦              ¦             ¦
¦ For example, to reinitialize some class attributes used by the methods.  ¦              ¦             ¦
¦-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------¦
¦ Execute after each test method.                                          ¦ @After       ¦ @AfterEach  ¦
¦ Used with non-static method.                                             ¦              ¦             ¦
¦ For example, to roll back database modifications.                        ¦              ¦             ¦
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Most of annotations in both versions are same, but few differs.

[Reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3qo7nvjQ2Wg&feature=youtu.be)

**Order of Execution.**

Dashed box -> optional annotation.

[image]

Answer (score 18):

**Before and BeforeClass in JUnit**

The function `@Before` annotation will be executed before each of test function in the class having `@Test` annotation but the function with `@BeforeClass` will be execute only one time before all the test functions in the class.

Similarly function with `@After` annotation will be executed after each of test function in the class having `@Test` annotation but the function with `@AfterClass` will be execute only one time after all the test functions in the class.

**SampleClass**

```
public class SampleClass {
    public String initializeData(){
        return "Initialize";
    }

    public String processDate(){
        return "Process";
    }
 }
```

**SampleTest**

```
public class SampleTest {

    private SampleClass sampleClass;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClassFunction(){
        System.out.println("Before Class");
    }

    @Before
    public void beforeFunction(){
        sampleClass=new SampleClass();
        System.out.println("Before Function");
    }

    @After
    public void afterFunction(){
        System.out.println("After Function");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClassFunction(){
        System.out.println("After Class");
    }

    @Test
    public void initializeTest(){
        Assert.assertEquals("Initailization check", "Initialize", sampleClass.initializeData() );
    }

    @Test
    public void processTest(){
        Assert.assertEquals("Process check", "Process", sampleClass.processDate() );
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
Before Class
Before Function
After Function
Before Function
After Function
After Class
```

**In Junit 5**

```
@Before = @BeforeEach
@BeforeClass = @BeforeAll
@After = @AfterEach
@AfterClass = @AfterAll
```

Answer (score 12):

**JUnit @BeforeEach, @AfterEach, @BeforeAll, @AfterAll**

`@Before`(JUnit4) -> `@BeforeEach`(JUnit5) - method is called **before** every test

`@After`(JUnit4) -> `@AfterEach`(JUnit5) - method is called **after** every test

`@BeforeClass`(JUnit4) -> `@BeforeAll`(JUnit5) - **static** method is called **before** executing all tests in this class. It can be a large task as starting server, read file, making db connection...

`@AfterClass`(JUnit4) -> `@AfterAll`(JUnit5) - **static** method is called **after** executing all tests in this class.

Answer (score 2):

```
import org.junit.Assert
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.BeforeClass
import org.junit.Test

class FeatureTest {
    companion object {
        private lateinit var heavyFeature: HeavyFeature
        @BeforeClass
        @JvmStatic
        fun beforeHeavy() {
            heavyFeature = HeavyFeature()
        }
    }

    private lateinit var feature: Feature

    @Before
    fun before() {
        feature = Feature()
    }

    @Test
    fun testCool() {
        Assert.assertTrue(heavyFeature.cool())
        Assert.assertTrue(feature.cool())
    }

    @Test
    fun testWow() {
        Assert.assertTrue(heavyFeature.wow())
        Assert.assertTrue(feature.wow())
    }
}
```

Same as

```
import org.junit.Assert
import org.junit.Test

 class FeatureTest {
    companion object {
        private val heavyFeature = HeavyFeature()
    }

    private val feature = Feature()

    @Test
    fun testCool() {
        Assert.assertTrue(heavyFeature.cool())
        Assert.assertTrue(feature.cool())
    }

    @Test
    fun testWow() {
        Assert.assertTrue(heavyFeature.wow())
        Assert.assertTrue(feature.wow())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic difference between all these annotations is as follows -

1. **@BeforeEach** - Use to run a common code before( eg setUp) each test method
   execution. analogous to JUnit 4’s @Before.
2. **@AfterEach** - Use to run a common code after( eg tearDown) each test method execution. analogous to JUnit 4’s @After.
3. **@BeforeAll** - Use to run once per class before any test execution. analogous to JUnit 4’s @BeforeClass.
4. **@AfterAll** - Use to run once per class after all test are executed. analogous to JUnit 4’s @AfterClass.

All these annotations along with the usage is defined on [Codingeek - Junit5 Test Lifecycle](https://www.codingeek.com/tutorials/junit/junit5-test-lifecycle-beforeall-beforeeach-afterall-aftereach/)

Answer (score 0):

`@BeforeClass` will be run before the entire test suits whereas `@Before` will be run  is executed before each test, while `@BeforeClass` runs once before the entire test fixture. If your test class has ten tests, `@Before` code will be executed ten times, but `@BeforeClass` will be executed only once.