# How make webdriver not to close browser window after each test?

Tags: java, testing, selenium, junit

I'm new in both Selenium WebDriver and Java. I have some webservices on my site on page /someservice.php. I've wrote few tests on Selenuim and they work fine. Code example (Main Class):

```
    public class SiteClass {
    static WebDriver driver;
    private static boolean findElements(String xpath,int timeOut ) {
public static void open(String url){
        //Here we initialize the firefox webdriver
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(url);
    }
    public static void close(){
        driver.close();
    }
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait( driver, timeOut );
            try {
                if( wait.until( ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated( By.xpath( xpath ) ) ) != null ) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } catch( TimeoutException e ) {
                return false;
            }}
    public static Boolean CheckDiameter(String search,String result){
          driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='search_diam']")).sendKeys(search);
          WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
          WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='ac_results'][last()]/ul/li")));
          WebElement searchVariant=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ac_results'][last()]/ul/li"));
          Actions action = new Actions(driver);
          action.moveToElement(searchVariant).perform();
          driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='ac_over']")).click();
          Boolean iselementpresent = findElements(result,5);
          return iselementpresent;
      }
    }
```

Code Example (Test Class)

```
    @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class DiamTest {@Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> diams() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
            { "111", "//div[@class='jGrowl-message']",true},
            { "222", "//div[@class='jGrowl-message']",false},
            { "333", "//div[@class='jGrowl-message']",true},
        });
    }
    private String inputMark;
    private String expectedResult;
    private Boolean assertResult;

    public DiamTest(String mark, String result, boolean aResult) {
        inputMark=mark;
        expectedResult=result;
        assertResult=aResult;
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }

    /**
     * Test of CheckDiameter method, of class CableRu.
     */
    @Test
    public void testCheckDiameter() {
        SiteClass obj=new SiteClass();
         obj.open("http://example.com/services.php");
        assertEquals(assertResult, obj.CheckDiameter(inputMark, expectedResult));
        obj.close();
    }

}
```

Now I have 2 tests like that with 3 parameters each (total 6 variants).  As you can see in every variant I create new browser window and when I run all 6 variants that take too much time (up to 80 seconds).

How can I run all variants in one browser window to speed up my tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move contents of *public static void close()* method from your SiteClass to tearDownClass() method in DiamTest class. In this way the browser window will be closed when the class execution finished (because of @AfterClass annotation). Your code then should look like this:

```
//DiamTest class
@AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
        driver.close();
    }
```

It's also a good practice to move browser window initialization to setUpClass() method which will be executed before each test class (according to @BeforeClass annotation)

```
//DiamTest class
@BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
        //Here we initialize the firefox webdriver
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(url);
    }
```

Comment: You can find more about those annotations here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295578/difference-between-before-and-beforeclass?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is share your help class with all your tests, this mean, you should create an instance of **SiteClass** inside your **setUpClass** method.
This method are annotated with @BeforeClass assuring your test class will create this method will be executed before all the test be executed.

You can read more about @BeforeClass in jUnit [doc](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html): or have a simple overview in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20295618/1133742) response.

You will also need do some rewrite some code to allow share the driver with the another test, something like this:

```
    @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
    public class DiamTest {

            @Parameters
        public static Collection<Object[]> diams() {
            return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
                { "111", "//div[@class='jGrowl-message']",true},
                { "222", "//div[@class='jGrowl-message']",false},
                { "333", "//div[@class='jGrowl-message']",true},
            });
        }
        private String inputMark;
        private String expectedResult;
        private Boolean assertResult;

        private static SiteUtil siteUtil; 

        public DiamTest(String mark, String result, boolean aResult) {
            inputMark=mark;
            expectedResult=result;
            assertResult=aResult;
        }

        @BeforeClass
        public static void setUpClass() {
            siteUtil = new SiteUtil();
        }

        @AfterClass
        public static void tearDownClass() {
            siteUtil.close();
        }

        @Test
        public void testCheckDiameter() {
            siteUtil.open("http://example.com/services.php");
            assertEquals(assertResult, obj.CheckDiameter(inputMark, expectedResult));
        }

    }
```

and:

```
    public class SiteClass {
            static WebDriver driver;

            public SiteClass() {
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            }

            public void open(String url){
                driver.get(url);
            }

            ...
```

Tip:
You should read about the [TestPyramid](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestPyramid.html).

Since functional tests are expensive, you should care about what is really necessary test. This article is about this.