# Why @BeforeClass in JUnit is static in nature

Tags: java, junit

In JUnit, why `@BeforeClass` is marked static? What is the significance in doing so?

And for every `xxxTest()` method, does Junit creates a new instance of the class?
https://martinfowler.com/bliki/JunitNewInstance.html

If yes why so?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20295618/7605325

Answer (score 3):

Did you read any of the JUnit docs?

Straight from the [@BeforeClass](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) docs:

> Sometimes several tests need to share computationally expensive setup
> ...
> Annotating a public static void no-arg method with @BeforeClass causes it to be run once before any of the test methods in the class.
> ...

Straight from the [@Test](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html) docs:

> ...
> To run the method, JUnit first constructs a fresh instance of the class then invokes the annotated method.
> ...

Comment: Why are @BeforeClass methods required to be static?