# JUnit @Before vs @Rule

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I understand that,

- `@Before` and `@BeforeClass` run before each test, or the entire test class, respectively
- `@Rule` and `@ClassRule` wraps each test, or the entire test class, respectively.

Let's say I need to initialize some data before each test method,

**How do I decide between using `@Before` and `@Rule`? Under what conditions is one preferred over another?** The same question also goes for `@BeforeClass` vs.`@ClassRule`.

Comment: A possible duplicate was suggested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295578, but that question does not address when to use `@Rule` vs. `@Before`

Comment: Its far from duplicate

Comment: https://singhajit.com/junit-rules/

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In order to use `@Rule`, you require a class that implements `TestRule`(preferred) or `MethodRule`, as can be read [here](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Rule.html). 
Whereas `@Before` and `@After` require a new method to be written in every test case, `@Rule` does not because it is only an instantiation of already existing code.

So, if you would use `@Before` and `@After` for `setUp()` and `tearDown()` that you'll be using in many test cases, it is actually a better idea to use `@Rule` because of `code reuse`. If you have a test case that requires a unique `@Before` and/or `@After`, then these annotations are preferable.

For a bit more elaborate answer with a couple examples, take a look [here](http://www.singhajit.com/junit-rules/). Ajit explains it very well.

Answer (score 12):

Indeed, as @Quwin suggested, accoridng to [JUnit 4.12 API doc](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TestRule.html),

> `TestRule` can do everything that could be done previously with
>   methods annotated with `@Before`, `@After`, `@BeforeClass`, or
>   `@AfterClass`, but `TestRule`s are **(1) more powerful**, and **(2) more easily shared
>   between projects and classes.**

---

Ways that `TestRule`s are *more powerful*:

There are known implementing classes of the `TestRule`, which are some usefuls rules you can use out-of-the-box,

> For examples of how this can be useful, see these provided TestRules, or write your own:
>
> - `ErrorCollector`: collect multiple errors in one test method
> - `ExpectedException`: make flexible assertions about thrown exceptions
> - `ExternalResource`: start and stop a server, for example
> - `TemporaryFolder`: create fresh files, and delete after test
> - `TestName`: remember the test name for use during the method
> - `TestWatcher`: add logic at events during method execution
> - `Timeout`: cause test to fail after a set time
> - `Verifier`: fail test if object state ends up incorrect

Another benefit of rules, is that multiple rules can be used in a single test case. You may want to use `RuleChain` to specify the order in which the rules should be run.

Comment: Since `junit 4.13` the RuleChain can be replaced with an [order](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.13/org/junit/Rule.html#order()) element.