# What is difference between BeforeClass (Junit 4 ) and BeforeEach(Junit5)

Tags: junit, junit4, junit5

Both the annotations are used to signal that the annotated method should be executed before each Test method in the current test class.

Then why do we have changed the annotation from **@BeforeClass - Junit 4 To @BeforeEach Junit 5**  ?

is there anything additional that have been added in junit 5 that i am missing ?

Similar case for other annotations.

Comment: No, that's not what BeforeClass is for. Read the javadoc. But names have been changed because... they thought the new names were better. Since it's a new, incompatible version, why not change the names?

Comment: `@Before` was renamed to `@BeforeEach` (and `@BeforeClass` was renamed to `@BeforeAll`). As you already mentioned, they are "executed before each test method". So this is a good new name.

Comment: Thanks for checking this. BeforeClass is also used to  run once before any of the test methods in the class so both are same. it's of if they have just changed the name.i wanted to know if they have added any additional stuff in new annotations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main functionality added is more fine-grained control over the [Test Instance Lifecycle](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-instance-lifecycle), for example through `@TestInstance` annotations. I presume this was one of the reasons to change the names of the old `@Before` and `@BeforeClass` annotations.

The old (JUnit4) `@Before` and the new (JUnit5) `@BeforeEach` are similar in that they are executed anew before *every* `@Test` method in a test class. So if your class has 10 test methods, the `@BeforeEach` method is executed 10 times.

The old (JUnit4) `@BeforeClass` and the new (JUnit5) `@BeforeAll` are similar in that they are both executed just *once*, before any of the tests in the class. So even if your class has 10 tests, the `@BeforeAll` method is executed just once.

The suggestion made in the question that `@BeforeClass` was renamed to `@BeforeEach` is thus *incorrect*.

For more information, see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45037910/165292) on the difference between @Before, @BeforeClass, @BeforeEach and @BeforeAll.

Answer (score 2):

There are some changes related that require the test class to be annotated with `@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)` first. This will create a new test instance once per test class instead of per method.

As a result, you can use `@BeforeAll` and `@AfterAll` for non-static methods as well as on interface default methods. It also allows you to use `@BeforeAll` and `@AfterAll` in `@Nested` test classes.

If you use `Lifecycle.PER_CLASS` you have to remember that if your tests rely on state stored in instance variables you might have to reset that state in `@BeforeEach` and `@AfterEach`.