# How to stub methods sooner than @Before block?

Tags: android, junit, kotlin

I initialize my ViewModel at top level, and as it initializes, it calls its `init {}` block, which then calls methods that I stub in @Before block.

Although all the tests are passed, NullPointerExceptions is thrown in methods that I call in `init {}`. I tried to `lateinit` my `ViewModel` in `@Before` block. It didn't work.

```
// AViewModelTest.kt
private val repoMock: ARepository = mock()
private val viewModel: AViewModel = AViewModel(repoMock)

@Before
fun setup() {
    // method stubbing
    `when`(repoMock.getSmth()).thenReturn(response)
}


// AViewModel.kt
constructor(repo: ARepository) {}

init {
    onStartLoading(repo)
}

fun onStartLoading(repo: ARepository) {
    val response = repo.getSmth()
    handleResponse(response) // response is null here -> NullPointerException
}
```

Comment: Could you add some code as well?

Comment: You could try the @BeforeClass annotation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295578/difference-between-before-beforeclass-beforeeach-and-beforeall

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: @tynn updated the question

Comment: `init` blocks are equivalent to constructor bodies, and so they will always be called before any methods. This is expected behavior. `repo` is `null` when `onStartLoading(repo)` is called from `init`.

Comment: @Brucelet I tried to `lateinit viewModel` in `@Before` block, but it didn't work for some reason.

Comment: The `@Before` block is called after `init`, so initializing in `@Before` doesn't help you here. Probably a better solution is to move the code from the `init` block into the `setup()` function instead.

Comment: @MasterQueue it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, `lateinit` in @Before did the thing. The problem occurred because I had an implicit reference to Android `Context` in my ViewModel.