# @BeforeAll Method as non-static

Tags: java, junit5

I was able to implement a non-static setup method with `@BeforeAll` annotation.
It seems to be working correctly as it only gets called once.
I am bit confused, as the documentation for `@BeforeAll` says the method has to be static. Can someone explain to me why my setup works anyway?

My code:

```
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
@SpringJUnitWebConfig(locations = { "classpath:service.xml" }) 
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Documented 
@Inherited 
public class MyTest {
    @BeforeAll
    public void setup() throws Exception {...}
}
```

Comment: Please show your full code.

Comment: If the given answer does not clarify your point, you should show THE FULL code which includes at lest a complete test class with imports and annotations. Why? Because anything could make a difference.

Comment: I have add the annotations I was using. thank you.

Comment: And indeed they reveal what’s going on :-)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You simply need to annotate your test class (that contains the `@BeforeAll` method) with the snippet below and you'll be good to go.

```
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
```

Comment: Another option is: Add file junit-platform.properties and write: junit.jupiter.testinstance.lifecycle.default = per_class

Answer (score 40):

If you want use non-static `@BeforeAll` and `@AfterAll` methods you should [change test instance lifecycle](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-instance-lifecycle-changing-default) to `per_class`.

Look there: [2.10. Test Instance Lifecycle](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-instance-lifecycle)

Comment: I was using @TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS). Now I know that was the reason it was allowing me run non-static @beforeAll method. Thank you