# @BeforeClass Method not runing before each class

Tags: java, xml, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

I have two classes and each class contains 2 test cases and Test1 class having one method with @BeforeClass as per me this method should run before Test2 class too but it is not running.

```
    package WebPackage;

    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    public class Test1 {
        @BeforeClass
        public void test1() {

            System.out.println("printing Before Class Method");
        }
        @Test (priority = 1)
    public void test2() {

            System.out.println("printing test_2");
        }

        @Test (priority = 3)
    public void test3() {

            System.out.println("printing test_3");
        }
    }
```

Test2

```
    package WebPackage;

    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    public class Test2 {

        @Test (priority = 1)
        public void test4() {

                System.out.println("printing test_4");
            }

            @Test (priority = 3)
        public void test5() {

                System.out.println("printing test_5");
            }
    }
```

Xml file

```
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
    <suite name="Menu">
      <test name="WebPackage">
        <classes>
          <class name="WebPackage.Test1"/>
         <class name="WebPackage.Test2"/>
        </classes>
      </test> <!-- Test -->
    </suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Console

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.0.0
printing Before Class Method
printing test_2
printing test_3
printing test_4
printing test_5

===============================================
Menu
Total tests run: 4, Passes: 4, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: The `@BeforeClass` in your example behaves exactly as I would expect. see
http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html.

You could put the `@BeforeClass` in a superclass of test1 and test2, would that do what you try to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a `BaseTest` class with `@BeforeClass` annotation and then each Test class extend with BaseTest.

BaseTest:

```
public class BaseTest {
    @BeforeClass
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("printing Before Class Method");
    }
}
```

Test1:

```
public class Test1 extends BaseTest {
    @Test (priority = 1)
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println("printing test_2");
    }

    @Test(priority = 3)
    public void test3() {
        System.out.println("printing test_3");
    }
}
```

Test2:

```
public class Test2 extends BaseTest {
    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void test4() {
        System.out.println("printing test_4");
    }

    @Test (priority = 3)
    public void test5() {
        System.out.println("printing test_5");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
printing Before Class Method
printing test_2
printing test_3
printing Before Class Method
printing test_4
printing test_5
===============================================
Menu
Total tests run: 4, Passes: 4, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Answer (score 0):

`BeforeClass` runs only once when Test class is started. Hence. it executes only once per test class. Use `@Before` if you want to execute it with every test method in test class.

Read ref - [Difference between @Before, @BeforeClass, @BeforeEach and @BeforeAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295578/difference-between-before-beforeclass-beforeeach-and-beforeall)

Answer (score 0):

`@BeforeClass` will run only once before running any method annotated with `@Test` in that class. It will not run again for any method in your `Test2` class.