# Why does this test pass?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, tdd, hamcrest

I need your help to understand a unit (method) behaviors within a unit test class shown below.

```
public void updateAccount(Account account) {
 if (!accountExists(account.getAccountNo())) { 
throw new AccountNotFoundException();
} 
accounts.put(account.getAccountNo(), account); 
}
```

The method shown above tells me that the exception will be thrown if the account is not found

However the 2nd test ( `updateNotExistedAccount`) method shown below shows that it's expected that the method above (`updateAccount` ) should throw an exception to past the test. However, `newAccount` is already initialized /created within the `createNewAccount` so it exists already. So I assume that the `updateNotExistedAccount` will failed the test (because `updateAccount` won't throw exceptions in that case ), however `updateNotExistedAccount` passed.

```
    public class InMemoryAccountDaoTests {
    private static final String NEW_ACCOUNT_NO = "998";
     private Account newAccount; 
    private InMemoryAccountDao accountDao;

   @Before 
    public void init() { 

     newAccount = new Account(NEW_ACCOUNT_NO, 200); 
    accountDao = new InMemoryAccountDao(); 
    }

        @Test
         public void createNewAccount() { 
         accountDao.createAccount(newAccount);
        assertEquals(accountDao.findAccount(NEW_ACCOUNT_NO), newAccount); }



        @Test(expected = AccountNotFoundException.class)
         public void updateNotExistedAccount() { accountDao.updateAccount(newAccount);
        }
```

Is it wrong if I assume `updateNotExistedAccount` will fail the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the data are persisted from one test to another. 
Try to clean the data after each test.

```
@After
public void clean(){
    // this method will be run after each single @Test method
    // you can use this to clean all resoruces after a test. in your case for example
    accountDao.deleteById(newAccount.getId());
}
```

For your test to be complete, and to test the update, I would do something like this:

```
@Test
public void updateExistingAccount() {
    accountDao.createAccount(newAccount);
    dbAccount = accountDao.findAccount(newAccount.getId);
    dbAccount.setName("");
    dbAccount.setSurname("");
    // etc...
    accountDao.updateAccount(dbAccount);
    dbAccountUpdated = accountDao.findAccount(newAccount.getId);
    assertEquals(accountDao.findAccount(dbAccountUpdated.getId()), dbAccount);
}
```

**UPDATE** 
Consider also that `@Before` and `@After` runs respectively before and after each single test.
`@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` respectively before and after all tests.

With the use of these 4 methods you can start always the test with the desired dataset, and after the test clean everything as it were. 
Please see: 
[Difference between @Before, @BeforeClass, @BeforeEach and @BeforeAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295578/difference-between-before-beforeclass-beforeeach-and-beforeall)

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I thought @Before will run only once.

Comment: Yes, please consider also that `@Before` and `@After` runs respectively before and after each single test. `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` respectively before and after all tests. (updated the answer for more visibility) Have a nice evening.

Answer (score 1):

To properly check need to look at your `newAccount` code as well as what all you are Mocking.

- Check your `@Before` method as that will run before every `@Test`
- Check if which test is running first when you run your suite