# How JUnit manages running @BeforeClass only once which is defined inside the test class

Tags: java, testing, junit

I very much understand what `@BeforeClass` is. It is executed once before JUnit test run is started & `@Before` method is executed before every test case.
My question is regarding a very old post by a very senior stackoverflow user (Péter Török
68.8k) Please refer [stackoverflow question]
  [1]: [JUnit: using constructor instead of @Before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094081/junit-using-constructor-instead-of-before/6094143#6094143) which was posted about 2 yrs ago but on JUnit4. so I think it is still valid and true.

Here he mentions

> @Before is equivalent to constructor of test class

and

> JUnit creates a new instance of the test class for each @Test,

So how does JUnit manage running `@BeforeClass` only once which is defined inside the test class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Methods annotated with `@BeforeClass` must be static. JUnit doesn't need any instance of the test class to call it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, jUnit could run the method annotated with `@BeforeClass` at time of class loading, that is like you would implement on your own with a static initializer.

You get also the hint that jUnit is doing something like this by the fact that `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` annotated methods must be static.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `@BeforeClass` has to be a static method. Once it is static, JUnit knows how to run it once.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes several tests need to share computationally expensive setup (like logging into a database). While this can compromise the independence of tests, sometimes it is a necessary optimization. Annotating a `public static` void no-arg method with `@BeforeClass` causes it to be run once before any of the test methods in the class. The `@BeforeClass` methods of superclasses will be run before those the current class. Static methods are not belongs to instances of the class. Those are properties of the class.